# Max Retries Exceeded and SSL Errors

Tags: geopy, nominatim

I'm looking for some assistance in resolving this error.
geopy.exc.GeocoderUnavailable: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='nominatim.openstreetmap.org', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /search?q=ADDRESS&format=json&limit=1 (Caused by SSLError(SSLCertVerificationError(1, '[SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: self signed certificate in certificate chain (_ssl.c:1108)')))

I've already tried installing certifi. I've tried adding time out restrictions. I tried to install ssl, but I'm receiving an error for that indicating that there is no matching distribution found for ssl. I've tried to connect to the Nominatim geocoder using two computers with the same error. Any thoughts on how to resolve? I've only tried to query 5-6 times, so I would guess that would be within limits of reasonable tries. Any thoughts appreciated.

Comment: If you're using Windows, try to load https://nominatim.openstreetmap.org/ in the Internet Explorer first, see https://github.com/geopy/geopy/issues/212#issuecomment-375685743 . If that wouldn't help either, you may try to switch geopy to the certifi store, see `default_ssl_context` section at https://geopy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/#geopy.geocoders.options